# Packer attach existing ebs-volume to AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, packer

I am trying to attach an existing amazon ebs-volume with some pre-loaded information on my AMI using packer but I haven't found a way to do it.

Looking at the packer documentation I'm pretty sure that what I'm looking for is a amazon-ebssurrogate builder. But I don't see any option to specify the volume-id. I have seen many examples on how to create a new volume and attach it. But not any example of doing this with an existing volume. This is my current packer file at the moment:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "modified_by": "{{env `USER`}}",
        "aws_access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
        "aws_secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
        "aws_bamboo_ami": "{{user `aws_ubuntu_ami`}}"
    },

    "builders": [{
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "vpc_id": "vpc-12345",
        "subnet_id": "subnet-12345",
        "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
        "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "availability_zone": "us-east-1b",
        "source_ami": "{{user `aws_ubuntu_ami`}}",
        "instance_type": "m5.xlarge",
        "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
        "ami_name": "{{user `modified_by`}} bamboo-server-stock-ami {{timestamp}}",
        "tags": {
            "Name": "Stock-Bamboo-Ubuntu-Server-Image",
            "business_unit": "Commercial:Release",
            "service": "opensource.atlassian.com",
            "resource_owner": "{{user `modified_by`}}",
            "service_tier": "app",
            "environment": "dev"
        }
    }],

    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "shell", 
            "scripts": [
                "../scripts/ansible-ubuntu.sh"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ansible-local",
            "playbook_dir": "../playbooks",
            "playbook_file": "../playbooks/bamboo-server.yml",
            "extra_arguments": "-vvvvv"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any feedback or pointers on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a snapshot of the volume and reference that in either [ami_block_device_mappings](https://packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#snapshot_id) or *launch_block_device_mappings*.